# Using variables VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple code to check correct answers in an excel sheet:

```
   If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test1").Range("B13") = "X" Or ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test1").Range("B13") = "x" Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test1").Range("A9") = "CORRECT"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test1").Range("A9").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)

Else
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test1").Range("A9") = "INCORRECT"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test1").Range("A9").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
```

I need to find a way to make "B13" a variable, same for "A9"
Problem is the variable needs to hold value ("incorrect") but also needs to change color of the cell, so if I declare the variable as "string", I cannot change the color of the cell.

They show up again later after a few conditions:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test1").Range("B13") = "X"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test1").Range("B13").Font.Bold = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test1").Range("B13").Font.Color = vbGreen
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test1").Range("C13").Font.Bold = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test1").Range("C13").Font.Color = vbGreen
```

so, the variable also needs to allow me to change the font.

I tried:

```
Dim i as string
Dim i as range
```

...but I always get an error.

sometihng like:

```
Dim i as String
i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test1").Range("B13")

i.value = "correct"
i.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
i.Font.Bold = True
i.Font.Color = vbGreen
```

Comment: Pls. check `Dim i as Range
Set i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test1").Range("B13")`
With object `Set` must be used.

Comment: Recommendation: `i` is typically used as an iterator variable. Use something more meaningful, like `Dim rng As Range` or `Dim cell As Range`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting rng as range and using set as Black Cat suggested worked

Comment: Just as an fyi: a Range variable is an Object variable, every Object variable needs to be set, not just given the value, i.e. `Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range` with `Set wb = ThisWorkbook : Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Test") : Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A50000")`. The i - as BigBen mentioned - is more often used as the variable used in a loop and since loops can get big, it's usually declared as a Long variable, i.e. `Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To rng.Cells.Count`